# How to test a trigger relying on PartnerNetworkConnection and PartnerNetworkConnection?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, salesforce2salesforce

(I'll refer to `A` as the sending instance and `B` as the receiving instance)

We have a trigger on instance `B` re-populating a regular lookup field. It is triggered when there's a change to a hidden field containing the parent ID of a record from the instance `A`. When there's a change to this field (let's say from `null` to a valid ID), the trigger is requesting the `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` record where the `ParentRecordId` field is equal to the new ID and where the `ConnectionId` is equal to an ID set in a Custom Setting. Then, the trigger updates the local `Parent Record` lookup in `B` using the `LocalRecordId` field.

Now, I'm wondering how I can unit test this module. Insert DML requests on `PartnerNetworkConnection` are not allowed, while all the DML requests I make on `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` are giving me this error:

`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_PARTNER_NETWORK_STATUS, invalid status for partner network operation: []`

Any idea?

Comment: It's been a while since I've dealt with S2S, but I was able to unit test insertion of PNRC records about a year ago. My unit test code had SeeAllData=true set, and I first queried for a pre-existing PartnerNetworkConnection and used that as the ConnectionId for the inserted record. That may help you out, although it obviously makes your unit tests data-dependent.

Comment: @jkraybill Yes, I thought of that idea, but still didn't put it in place for the same reason (unit test being data dependant). I'll keep on searching for a solution. If I find no solution, ah well, it will not be the only time I need to apply minor tweaks to pass coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the comment @jkraybill had above, I found the only way to actually test was to set **seeAllData** to true.

As you mentioned in your post, you cannot use DML on the PartnerNetworkConnection in the unit test. If you are adamant about not using **seeAllData**, you could abstract out the ParterNetworkConnection pieces in a way that they do not get run in a unit test. While this would leave you with a suboptimal amount of code coverage, it would at least cover the remainder of your code (any business logic around SF2SF, excluding the actual connection itself).