# S2S Test Data Isolation

Tags: test-data-isolation, salesforce-to-salesforce, salesforce2salesforce

Goal - Avoid using SeeAllData=true for testmethods against APEX code that inserts `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` objects (to test outbound sharing)

**What I believe to be true**

1. `PartnerNetworkConnection` object can not be mocked - DML and test.loadData() both fail
2. `PartnerNetworkConnection` rows are available for query even in a testmethod marked simply as `@IsTest`
3. `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` rows can be inserted in an `@IsTest` testmethod. However, the inserted rows have to be assigned to a `PartnerNetworkConnection` with `connectionStatus` of Active.

OK, not great but as we're only relying on a real active Connection but otherwise we've isolated test data.

**Now, here is where I am stumped**

1. If you insert a `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` (PNRC) through code (such as an Account), it will be assigned by SFDC a status of 'Invite'.
2. If you then try and insert a `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` for, say, an Opportunity, where the parentRecordId is the Account you successfully inserted in #1 above, the insert will fail with `INVALID_PARTNER_NETWORK_STATUS`.  This is because the PNRC for the Account hasn't been moved to status = 'Sent' by SFDC.

**So, how to mock the PNRC status to 'Sent' for the parent (e.g. Account) so the PNRC insert of the Opportunity succeeds?**

Here is what I tried, all of which failed:

- Test.loadData(...)  *// internal Salesforce error*
- DML update on PNRC  *// SObject is not updateable*
- Placing Test.stopTest() after the PNRC insert of the Account, signalling SFDC to do "async-y stuff" like it does for future and batches.  *//  INVALID_PARTNER_NETWORK_STATUS on the PNRC insert for the Opportunity*
- Json.deserialize(..) into a PNRC object  *// doesn't help as the PNRC DML insert validates against a real database record, not an in-memory sObject*

*Research*

- [S2S Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practices_for_Salesforce_to_Salesforce) - relies on already shared objects to use in testmethods; however, I believe this was written before Test Data Isolation was a feature
- [SFSE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/14868/2602) - with similar conclusions but 12 months old
- Numerous SFDC Developer forum questions from 2012 and earlier; all with same issue

**Unsatisfactory options:**

**Option 1** - Give up my aversion to SeeAllData and hence, manage in every sandbox + PROD a known parent Account successfully shared on a known PartnerNetworkConnection via Custom Settings

**Option2** - Replace in my PROD code the line that does the Database.insert(..) on the PNRC with a method call to an interface which in PROD context does the DML but in testmethod context creates a local object that is verified by testmethod asserts (sort of a shadow database). But I'm not really testing the DML to verify it can actually work in the test.

**Option 3** - Get my code coverage as high as possible with as many asserts as possible; make my Apex code be loggable and fault tolerant (not addError a transaction just because of an S2S error).

I'm currently doing **Option 3** but I'd love to hear if one of the SFSE wizards have solved this issue.